# Why am I getting =0A inside emails being sent, where there should be a line break?

Tags: ruby, email

I'm getting `=0A` inside my emails where there should be a line break.

```
@article = DB[:posts][:nodeview_id => view, :nodeview => 'article']    
Pony.mail(:html_body => @article[:content], :reply_to => @email, :subject => "New article #{@article[:title]}", :headers => { "X-MC-Tags" => "feedback" } )
```

And #@article[:content]} in this context, is

> apples
>
> bananas

inside the database, no `\n` or `<br>` tags.

Here's how Pony is configured.

```
Pony.options = { :from => 'Compesh <donotreply@compesh.com>', :to => 'blahblahblah@emails.com', 
                   :via => :smtp, :via_options => { 
                      :address => 'smtp.mandrillapp.com', :port => '587', 
                      :user_name => 'XXX', :password => 'XXXXXX'
                      },
                   :headers => { "X-MC-AutoText" => "yes" }, :charset => 'utf-8' 
  
                 }
```

But in my emails I get

> apples=0Abananas

Pony doesn't let me choose the content type, I don't think.

Comment: What format are you using when sending the files? How are you viewing the email messages, in a MUA or directly on disk? `=0A` is an encoded line-feed, which should be translated by the MUA into a normal "\n"

Comment: I'm viewing them from Gmail but my app uses the Ramaze framework. https://gist.github.com/cc6b728e6c9832f8cf83

Comment: The problem isn't Ramaze, as it's a web framework. What (MTA) are you using to connect to your SMTP host when you send the mail? Either you are not preparing the body of the message correctly, or the MTA isn't handing it off to the internet correctly. Are you using MIME formatting, or plain text?

Comment: I don't know what MTA I'm using, because I'm using [Mandrill](http://mandrill.com) to operate the sending of my transactional email over SMTP. All I have is my SMTP login details. I used `:charset => 'utf-8'` to change the character encoding to UTF-8 and I'm still getting this issue.

Comment: It's not a charset issue. How are you creating `@message`? What are the line-ends? `"\n"`, or `"\r\n"`?

Comment: The line ends are just blank lines being stored in a database. The line feed and carriage return symbols do not exist. Those line ends don't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this by converting newlines to a `<br>` tag. It turns out it had nothing to do with the content type or encoding of the email at a..

```
mystring.gsub(/(?:\n\r?|\r\n?)/, '<br>')
```

This specially general regex function, has a way of covering DOS, *NIX, Mac and accidental invalid line endings.